# Modal not centering on screen, css

Tags: html, css

I am having some problem centering a modal, when i am using serverel modals on the same page.

So whenever i press the button within the circle, the modal opens. On the page there are 6 modals, each with unique ID's of course.

On the image below, you see that the first model is centeret - simply using hacks for this.

[image]

However when i press another model to pop-up, it is not centered as seen below:

[image]

So as i see it, the javascript doesn't take into account the width of the screen or something like that.

The following is the CSS for the modal:

```
element {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    left: 50%;
}
.reveal-modal {
    top: -180px !important;
    width: 750px;
    background: url("modal-gloss.png") no-repeat scroll -200px -80px #EEE;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

As you can see, i am using percentages, however the problem still occurs. What is it, that is going wrong with this modal, since it doesn't center all the modals?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or something for this? also are you using jquery modals for this or something else or creating your own?

Comment: Are some of the modals within an element that has `position: relative` applied?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: `left: 50%` does not center the element, this puts the left edge of the element at the center of the page. You should use certain positioning with `margin: auto` to center the element

Comment: Without a demo it's hard to tell, but from the screenshots it looks like maybe your modals are affecting each others layout, even though they are not visible. Setting `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` on elements will make them invisible, but still affect the layout of other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already positioning `.reveal-modal` absolutely all you need to do is set a proper offset to counter your `left: 50%` value.

Try setting `margin-left: -375px` on `.reveal-modal`. This is exactly half of the width (`750px`) of that element.

Comment: Yeah, of couse. This is the fastest and simplest solution of the mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to center an absolutely positioned element, here's the code that works **every time**, no hacks needed (no negative margins combined with 50% offsets), it's always vertically and horizontally centered inside its parent:

```
.element {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

See it here:

```css
.element {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Centered</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shomz, Thanks for your contribution. I will try this at sometime in the further development, as this will most likely work the best for a longer lasting solution. For the time being, i just needed a 'quick-fix'. But thanks again, and +1 for your solution.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. Absolutely, I just wanted you to remember this method as it's a life-saver for absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: This is a more reliable solution because it doesn't depend on knowing the width of an element, so the same rule can apply to elements of different widths or even elements of dynamic widths

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this for a modal popup:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
top: 50%;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.modal {
position: relative;
margin: auto;
border: 1px solid red;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
top: -100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpvLf87x/

In the `top: -100px;` part, the -100px should be half of the popups height, so if the popup is 500px tall, it should have `top: -250px` instead. The `margin: auto` will automatically center it horizontally no matter the width

Comment: What do you mean? The code shows how to horizontally and vertically center an element on the page, which is exactly what the question was asking

Comment: And is completely different/unrelated from OP's code. OP wanted their code fixed, not a replacement (as in 99% of the questions here).

Comment: Well the OP should be able to use my code to fix their code, I think that a generalized solution would be more helpful for anyone else who had a similar problem, which I believe is the purpose of this site anyways. And besides, it is kind of difficult to fix OP's code when only the css is provided